# Meteor can't activate an element with JQuery after template rendered with data from MongoDb

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor, semantic-ui

I know that similar questions (dealing with Meteor Blaze template and JQuery) has been asked here, but I tried many solutions and it didn't work.

Here's my problem with Meteor and JQuery.
I have a meteor blaze template called fruits:

```
<template name='fruits'>
    <select class="ui search dropdown" id='fruits'>
        <option value="">Fruit</option>
        {{#each fruits}} 
        <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```

I pull the list of items (fruits in this example dynamically from a mongo collection like this:

```
Template.fruits.helpers({
    "fruits": function () {
     return fruits.find();
   }
 });
```

I'm using semantic-ui module to style my dropdown list and add a search feature as you can see in class of select element. 
I need to activate the semantic dropdown module with JQuery only after the data is pulled from the database and all the options are rendered.

But the my dropdown component is always empty (semantic-ui shows no option) because the options are rendered after JQuery activates the dropdown.

The first solution that I have tried was putting this before my body tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fruits').dropdown();
        }
    );
</script>
```

But it's not working.

The other solution That I found here and I have tried was adding this to my javascript file:

```
 Template.fruits.rendered = function (){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        $('#fruits').dropdown();
    });
  };
```

But the second solution doesn't work neither.

Answer (score -1):

You must listen for the `onRendered` callback.

http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered

```
<template name="myPictures">
  <div class="container">
    {{#each pictures}}
      <img class="item" src="/{{.}}"/>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.myPictures.onRendered(function () {
  // Use the Packery jQuery plugin
  this.$('.container').packery({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    gutter: 10
  });
```

Comment: Does not work.  jQuery access to elements is not valid within onRendered.